# Why a local variable is carried over in Python for loop

Tags: python, algorithm

What's going on in this code:

```py
class Solution:
    def removeComments(self, source: List[str]) -> List[str]:
        in_block = False
        ans = []
        for line in source:
            print("current line:", line)
            i = 0
            if not in_block:
                newline = []
            while i < len(line):
                if line[i:i+2] == '/*' and not in_block:
                    in_block = True
                    i += 1
                elif line[i:i+2] == '*/' and in_block:
                    in_block = False
                    i += 1
                elif not in_block and line[i:i+2] == '//':
                    break
                elif not in_block:
                    print("line:", line, "line i:", line[i], "newline", newline)
                    newline.append(line[i])
                    print("newline after:", newline)
                i += 1
            if newline and not in_block:
                ans.append("".join(newline))
                print("ans:", ans)
        return ans
```

`newline` is created at each iteration of a line in `source` (if the block comment isn't open), so how does the code get `newline` with "a" when the current line is at "b"?

```
input: ["a/*comment", "line", "more_comment*/b"]
print:
current line: a/*comment
line: a/*comment line i: a newline []
newline after: ['a'] <= this makes sense, after removing everything after /*
current line: line <= this makes sense, we ignore this because the block comment is still open
current line: more_comment*/b <= at this last line, block comment is still open
line: more_comment*/b line i: b newline ['a'] <== this isn't supposed to happen
newline after: ['a', 'b'] <= how?
ans: ['ab']
```

At current line = "more_comment*/b" which is the item at index 2 of the input `source`, the `newline` should not be there because it was created inside the for loop.

I can understand [this solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-comments/discuss/109210/Simple-Python-one-pass-with-clear-inline-explanation!!!) because the `buffer` is created outside of the for loop and he clears it every time after appending to the `output`. However, the code above makes me totally confused.

Comment: Only one instance of `newline` exists during this run of the code.  `in_block` gets set on the first line, and remains set until the last line, thus preventing `newline` from ever being reassigned.

Comment: Thank you Jason. So how does the for loop move forward to the next line in `source`? I understand that `newline` is created during the first iteration and it remains there until the end of that specific iteration. How is it carried to other iteration of the for loop?

Comment: Unlike java, python doesn't have the concept of block-based scopes. There's one scope: the scope of the function and that's it. The variable doesn't get deleted when you start a new iteration

Comment: Thank you Paul. That is why. I'm trying to learn Python on my own. Would you mind answering the question so I can mark it as answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python doesn't have a concept of block-based scopes similar to e.g. Java. While still defining scopes by blocks, blocks are defined as one of the following:

- modules
- classes
- function definitions

and a few other that aren't relevant for this question. You can look up the details [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#structure-of-a-program).

For the above code this means that the name `newline` is bound in the first iteration of the loop and will then exist until leaving the current block (the function `removeComments`). For details on how variables are resolved and handled, see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names).